# How to do text vectorization in Torch as a model layer

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, torch, embedding

Is there a way to get a Torch model to do text-vectorization? In Torch, I can't find a way to do the vectorization inside the model. Every example I have found applies the vectorization inside the dataset. This is really inconvenient because when you want to apply your model to new data, you have to carry over the vectorization manually.

In TensorFlow/Keras there is a layer TextVectorization which makes the NN do the text-vectorization. This is useful because when I want to apply the model to new data, the model remembers the vectorization and applies it automatically.

Below you can see an example of building a model with TF using the TextVectorization layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras import layers

train_data, validation_data, test_data = tfds.load(
    name = "imdb_reviews", 
    split = ('train[:60%]', 'train[60%:]', 'test'),
    as_supervised = True
)

train_data = train_data.shuffle(10000).cache().batch(64).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Strips some HTML break tags '<br />'.
def custom_standardization(input_data):
    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
    stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, '<br />', ' ')
    return tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html, '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '')

vectorize_layer = layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize = custom_standardization,
    max_tokens = 10000,
    output_mode = 'int',
    output_sequence_length = 100
)

vectorize_layer.adapt(train_data.map(lambda x, y: x))


inputs = layers.Input(shape = (1, ), dtype = tf.string)
x = vectorize_layer(inputs)
x = layers.Embedding(10000, 16, name="embedding")(x)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = x)
```

Below is an example of a Torch dataset where text-vectorization is applied inside the dataset. Here, my dependent variable is iris.pedal_width and my independent is iris.species. If I want to run this model on new data, I have to carry over the data.le object to the new data. This dataset would be passed to a torch NN.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import seaborn as sns 
import numpy as np

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

class myDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df):
        labels = df['species'].values
        self.le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        train = self.le.fit_transform(labels)
        self.train = torch.as_tensor(train)
        
        self.targets = df['petal_width'].values

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.targets)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.train[idx], self.targets[idx]

data = myDataset(iris)
train_loader = DataLoader(data, batch_size = 10, shuffle = False)
```

For Torch, how can I do text-vectorization directly in the model and not in the dataset?